# validar (negar la entrada de cantidades negativas y cero) en un textfield

Tags: java, netbeans, validación

Ya niega el ingreso de un valor que no sea un digito, en el campo de la cantidad a comprar, pero no niega la entrada de 0 o cantidades negativas a comprar

```
public void btnAgregar (ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

        if(!"".equals(txtCantidad.getText())){
            if(cbxmodelo.getValue() != null){
                if(cbxcolor.getValue() != null){
                    switch(cbxmodelo.getValue().toString()){
                        case "Moto z":{
                            precio = 650;
                            break;
                        }
                        case "Moto x":{
                            precio = 750;
                            break;
                        }
                        case "Moto g":{
                            precio = 850;
                            break;
                        }
                        case "Moto e":{
                            precio = 950;
                            break;
                        }
                        case "Moto c":{
                            precio = 1050;
                            break;
                        }
                        default:{ 
                        }
                    }
                    int can=0;
                    try{ 
                        can = Integer.parseInt(txtCantidad.getText());

                        if ( Integer.parseInt(txtCantidad.getText()) < 0) {
                        throw new Exception("Error. Ingresa una cantidad entera positiva \n con dígitos entre 1 y 20.");
                        }
                        if ( can > 20) {
                        throw new Exception("El valor introducido no puede ser mayor a 20");
                        }

                    }
                    catch(Exception ex){
                        lblmensaje.setText("Error. Ingresa una cantidad entera positiva \n con dígitos entre 1 y 20."); 
                    }


Agradeceria mucho si me pudieran ayudar
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que debes hacer es crearte una clase para manejar excepciones personalizadas del tipo:

```
public class Excepcion extends Exception{

    private final String mess;
    public Excepcion(String mess){
        this.mess=mess;
    }
    public String getMess(){return this.mess;}
}
```

Después modificas el bloque try-catch de la siguiente forma:

```
int can;
        try {
            can = Integer.parseInt(txtCantidad.getText());

            if (can < 0) {
                throw new Excepcion("Error. Ingresa una cantidad entera positiva \n con dígitos entre 1 y 20.");
            } else if (can == 0) {
                throw new Excepcion("Error. No pude sesr 0.");
            } else if (can > 20) {
                throw new Excepcion("El valor introducido no puede ser mayor a 20");
            }

        } catch (Excepcion ex) {
            lblmensaje.setText(ex.getMess());
        }
```

Espero que te sirva.